# I have a jquery problem when using $.noConflict

Tags: jquery

Hi I have to use noConflict method in my project. But I have a problem about this.
İf I dont use this method, project is working correctly.
But if I use this method, I  have a error. How can I solve this problem.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict(); // İf I dont use this method, project is working correctly.
                    // But if I use this method, I  have a error 
  </script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function goster() {
        alert($("#TextBox1").val());
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onBlur="goster();" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `$.noConflict();` then you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function goster() {
        alert(jQuery("#TextBox1").val());
    }
  </script>
```

see demo. http://jsfiddle.net/UnUgP/3/

Comment: why it's not true? then how is it? refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ `$.noConflict();` releases the `$` with jQuery for the use of other libraries.

Comment: It didnt work on master page, I write a new message about it.

Comment: @ordukaya: It's because you are not loading jQuery correctly. where did u put the scripts? try `../../` in the url. `href="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"` or pick url.

Comment: @Mahesh, I have control this in Firefox and I see javascript file. But It didnt work any time.

Comment: @ordukaya: and the second error is you are giving wrong id in the function. `alert(jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1").val());` as you are using server side control the id generated contains extra `ContentPlaceHolder1_`