# Why doesn't my jQuery code work in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, asp.net-ajax, cross-browser

**EDITED**

Hi, I use masterpage. And I use formsauthentication in my project. I pull my data from SQL Server 2005. then in login.aspx, I call my pagemethod from jQuery. After all, I run my project in IE9.0, Chrome and Firefox. The project is correct. But this jQuery code is working only IE9.0.

My pagemethod, which is named LoginService, returns "0" or returnURL like "user/Default.aspx", then I control this tah if return of LoginService isn't "0" success will run the following:

```
alert("there isnt error: " + msg.d);
```

but, if there is an error, this will run:

```
alert("there is error: " + msg.d);
```

It is very interesting that

if I run this project in IE9, message shown like "there isnt error: user/Default.aspx"

but,

if I run this project in Chrome or Firefox, message shown like "there is error: undefined"

how can I run this project in all browsers?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#myContent_login").focus();
    jQuery("#myContent_submit_image").click(function () {
      jQuery("#login_form_spinner").show();
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Logon.aspx/LoginService",
        data: "{'username': '" + jQuery("#myContent_login").val() + "', 'password': '" + jQuery("#myContent_password").val() + "','isRemember': '" + jQuery("#myContent_remember_me").is(':checked') + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
          if (msg.d != 0) {
            alert("there isnt error: " + msg.d);
          }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
          alert("have error: " + msg.d);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: When you say "there is error: undefined" -- do you mean "there isnt error: undefined" or "have error: undefined"?  There's no code here that should give you the exact message "there is error," and I'm not sure which case is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you return false from your click handler to cancel the default submit:

```
jQuery("#myContent_submit_image").click(function () {

    jQuery('#login_form_spinner').show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Logon.aspx/LoginService",
        data: "{'username': '" + jQuery("#myContent_login").val() + "', 'password': '" + jQuery("#myContent_password").val() + "','isRemember': '" + jQuery("#myContent_remember_me").is(':checked') + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d != 0) {
                window.location.replace(msg.d);
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });

    return false; // THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
});
```

Also cleanup your AJAX call in order to properly encode parameters, like this:

```
jQuery("#myContent_submit_image").click(function () {
    jQuery('#login_form_spinner').show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Logon.aspx/LoginService",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username: jQuery("#myContent_login").val(), 
            password: jQuery("#myContent_password").val(),
            isRemember: jQuery("#myContent_remember_me").is(':checked')
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d != 0) {
                window.location.replace(msg.d);
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });

    return false; // THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick observation:

jQuery('login_form_spinner')

you need a `#` or a `.` in front of `login_form_spinner`.

**Update:**

you can look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dHyRz/) for an example. Note that the success and erro functions are different than you're example.

I can help more but would need to know the specific error.

Comment: I edited your detail but it isnt work with firefox and chrome. But it is working correctly in ie9

Answer (score 0):

like justin said you where missing the has or dot also mad changes to your data object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#myContent_login").focus();
    $("#myContent_submit_image").click(function () {
        $('#login_form_spinner').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Logon.aspx/LoginService",
            data: {
                "username":$("#myContent_login").val(),
                "password":$("#myContent_password").val(),
                "isRemember":$("#myContent_remember_me").is(':checked')
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d != 0) {
                alert("there isnt error: " + msg.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("have error: " + msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

but I suspect that your not returning json header or something like that

Comment: what is the status you get back ie 302 404

Comment: no problem about returning. I write that, on ie9 wverything is good, but in firefox and chrome. and I use jQuery instead of $ to .conflict() like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456750/i-have-a-jquery-problem-when-using-noconflict

Comment: if you do it like it just did it you don't have to say jQuery all day is all, if you notice I pass it the $ check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @ordukaya huh ? I can tell you i know nothing about asp

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for jQuery.[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) carefully, and you'll see that `success` and `error` use different arguments:

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

So your error handler should look like this:

```
error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
    alert("have error: " + status);
}
```

Once you're successfully getting the error message, you can figure out what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
jQuery('login_form_spinner').show();
```

Is it a typo in the post or in your original code?
I am assuming your are missing a "#" for your selector. Since IE handles this kind of error differently from FF and Chrome. You get different behavior across browsers.

Comment: can I send my project if you want. can u see to me

Comment: Sure, email me your project and I will take a look. weima.gm@gmail.com